# Regex to match word within a message

Tags: regex

I'm really new at regex and I'm trying to make a regex to find messages with only 1 word being the word "Hi" or some variations but exclude the message if the word "hi" is along with other words.

For example, I want the regex to match a message which includes only and only the word "hello" and set a flag to true, but if the message contains "hello I need help" the regex should not match and the flag should remain as false.

The regex should work with a list of words:

```
Hi
Hii
Hello
Hello sir
hi sir
hii sir
Hi sir/ma'am
Hello sir/ma'am
Hi there
Hello there
```

I tried this, trying to limit the number of characters but it didn't work `[hi|hello|Hi sir]{0,10}`

Comment: I don't understand what you want: Please show which of the lines in your sample data you want to match. Is it that you want to match lines that are exactly "hi", "hello" or "hi sir" with nothing else on the line?

Comment: This is not quite clear. Try `(?i)\bh(?:i+|ello)(?:(?:\s+|,\s*)(?:(?:sir|ma'am)|there)|$)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tRmoIJ/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match lines that are exactly "hi", "hello" or "hi sir" with nothing else on the line (case insensitively matched):

```
(?i)^(hi|hello|hi sir)$
```